# Installing windows 7 hid ubuntu on my machine.Can I access ubuntu again?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, multi-boot

I had ubuntu already installed on my laptop.I did not uninstall it.I installed windows 7 on my laptop.Now I can't access ubuntu.It's hidden.I thought I would get a choice of operating systems at the start but I dont. I want both OS on my machine.Can somebody please help me?
The Ubuntu files still exist on a seperate hard drive on my system.Its name is OS(D) .Windows 7 is installed on C.Can anybody tell me how do I get a choice of operating systems during system start up ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps:

1. Boot from a Ubuntu LiveCD.
2. Select **Try Ubuntu**.
3. Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>).
4. Execute the following commands:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install boot-repair
   sudo boot-repair
   ```
5. Follow the instructions.
6. Reboot.

This will re-install GRUB, which was removed by the Windows installer. You'll be able to into into both operating systems now.

Comment: i dont have a ubuntu live cd.Can't I reinstall grub from my windows?

Comment: Do you have the Ubuntu installer for Windows? I've never tried it, but it should be possible from there to.

Comment: Can't I download grub from the internet ?

Comment: The problem isn't downloading GRUB (it's already on your Ubuntu partition), but re-installing it. This involves writing to your Ubuntu partition, which – if it's formatted with ext2/3/4 – WIndows won't be able to access without additional drivers. I suppose this is possible (and I'll look into it), but I don't know how right now. It doesn't have to be GRUB; you could install any other boot manager that supports both Windows and Linux as well. –– If you don't mind me asking, how did you install Ubuntu without an installer or a Live CD?

Comment: The [boot-repair disk](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/) might be useful.

Comment: Ubuntu was already installed on my system.I did not uninstall or remove it.Installing windows 7 just hid the boot loader.I want to know how to unhide it.